# Code works in jsfiddle but not in chrome. - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have been working on a simple game menu for a game (That I have yet to do.)
The code works perfectly in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7mXPy/33/)
however when I open my local html document none of the javascript works, (console.log and other code works before my error) and I get an error, on my createMenu function: line 67, that says *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined*

Here's the code for the createMenu function (also on jsfiddle)

```
   var menu = document.getElementsByClassName("menu");
var menu2 = document.getElementsByClassName("menu2");
var createMenu = function()
{   
menu[0].style.display = "block";    <---- Error
menu[1].style.display = "block";
menu[2].style.display = "block";
menu2[0].style.display = "none" ;
menu2[1].style.display = "none" ;
menu2[2].style.display = "none" ;

};
createMenu();
```

Note: I tried to do the display block/none with a loop for less code, but it didn't seem to work at all, not even in jfiddle.

```
var createMenu = function()
{
    var i = 0;
while (i <3 ) {
    i++;

menu[i].style.display = "block";
menu2[i].style.display = "none" ;
    }
};
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: jsfiddle is set to wrap your code in the onload event.  Put simply, `menu` doesn't exist when your code runs outside of jsfiddle - you need to run it on page load.

Comment: Ok ill look up how to that. - not considered duplicate becasue that is jquery and I dont understand jquery

Comment: You also have a bunch of JavaScript errors with badly formatted code. Here is the fix that at least runs. https://jsfiddle.net/7mXPy/34/

Comment: I think you have the wrong jsfiddle page....

Comment: Please don't edit your question when you have a solution, just accept an answer. If you want to comment on the accepted answer, then you can do so with the comment feature rather then by editing your reply into the question.

Comment: Ok... The website had a little pop up and told me to edit it if you think its not a duplicate post. ?

Comment: @Quentin I'd marked this as a potential dupe of a similar question (something working in jsfiddle but not elsewhere), but it was jQuery based.  Didn't find an alternative form without jQuery before an answer was posted here and accepted anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because you load your JS code in the `head` element, meaning the JS is executed before the rendering of your body. You’ll have to either wait for the complete DOM loading or place your script at the end of the body:

```
         <!-- ... -->
         <script src="your-script.js"></script>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly, Im not sure why but it works!

Comment: Oh right because Javsascript thinks I dont have any html. Thanks again!